# How to print an error msg if the number guessed by the user is wrong on javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Basically i want the system to generate a random number within a given range(the range will be determined by the user in the input fields below) and print out messages to let user know if its too high or too low. I am able to generate a number however the number seems to be changing. I can be inputting the same number but it will tell me is too low, and too high next. How can i also limit the number of tries to 5 tries? Do I loop the entire function?**

```
<html> 
 table border="1" width="50%"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
        Enter a smaller number<br>
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <span id="wrongInput"></span><br>

        Enter a larger number<br>
        <input id="input2" type="text">
        <span id="wrongInput2"></span><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
        <br>

        
        <!-- guess the number -->
        <label for="guess">Guess the number</label><br>
        <input text="text" class="guessField" id="guessField">
        <span id="guessMessage"></span>
        <input type="button" onclick="guess()" value="Guess button"><br>
        <p>Output area</p>
        <textarea id="output" name="output" rows="5" style="width: 50%"></textarea>

    </td><br>
</tr> 
</table>

<script>
function guess() 
{
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessField").value; 

    //get the elements on lower and higher number 
    var min = document.getElementById("input").value; 
    var max = document.getElementById("input2").value; 
    //generate random number 
    var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);

    //output the msg
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
        
    if (guess == randomNo) 
    { 
        output.value = "You have guessed correctly! " + "(" + guess + ")"; 
    } else if (guess > randomNo)
    {
        output.value = "Number is too high! " + "(" + guess + ")";  
        guessNo++;
            
    } else { 
        output.value = "Number is too low! " + "(" + guess + ")"; 
        guessNo++;
    } 
    
} </script></html>
```

Comment: Every time you run the `guess()` function, you are also rerunning `var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);`, so of course your randomized number is new after every execution.

Comment: @Marc i've shifted my var randomNo + min + max out of the function guess() but now I'm getting 0 for all my numbers..

Comment: you also need to extract the `min` and `max` from the function or else it cant calculate the correct result

Answer (score 1):

split the value generate function and the guessing function,

```
ithin a given range(the range will be determined by the user in the input fields below) and print out messages to let user know if its too high or too low. I am able to generate a number however the number seems to be changing. I can be inputting the same number but it will tell me is too low, and too high next. How can i also limit the number of tries to 5 tries? Do I loop the entire function?

<html> 
 table border="1" width="50%"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
        Enter a smaller number<br>
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <span id="wrongInput"></span><br>

        Enter a larger number<br>
        <input id="input2" type="text">
        <span id="wrongInput2"></span><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
        <br>

        
        <!-- guess the number -->
        <label for="guess">Guess the number</label><br>
        <input text="text" class="guessField" id="guessField">
        <span id="guessMessage"></span>
        <input type="button" onclick="guess()" value="Guess button"><br>
        <p>Output area</p>
        <textarea id="output" name="output" rows="5" style="width: 50%"></textarea>

    </td><br>
</tr> 
</table>

<script>
function guess() 
{
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessField").value;

    //output the msg
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
        
    if (guess == randomNo) 
    { 
        output.value = "You have guessed correctly! " + "(" + guess + ")"; 
    } else if (guess > randomNo)
    {
        output.value = "Number is too high! " + "(" + guess + ")";  
        guessNo++;
            
    } else { 
        output.value = "Number is too low! " + "(" + guess + ")"; 
        guessNo++;
    } 
    
} </script>
```

add this snippet back in your `playFunction()`

```
    //get the elements on lower and higher number 
    var min = document.getElementById("input").value; 
    var max = document.getElementById("input2").value; 
    //generate random number 
    var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
```

so that your target only gets generated once when you pressed the play game button and won't be overwrote everytime the user guesses